# Select dynamic Columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Is it possible to traverse a table like this:

```
mysql> select * from `stackoverflow`.`Results`;
+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+
| ID           | TYPE    | CRITERIA_ID | RESULT |
+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+
|            1 | car     | env         | 1      |
|            2 | car     | gas         |        |
|            3 | car     | age         |        |
|            4 | bike    | env         | 1      |
|            5 | bike    | gas         |        |
|            6 | bike    | age         | 1      |
|            7 | bus     | env         | 1      |
|            8 | bus     | gas         | 1      |
|            9 | bus     | age         | 1      |
+--------------+---------+-------------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Into this:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+
| TYPE | env | gas | age |
+------+-----+-----+-----+
| car  | 1   |     |     |
| bike | 1   |     | 1   |
| bus  | 1   | 1   | 1   |
+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

The aim is to select all the `CRITERIA_ID`s and use them as a column.
As rows i like to use all the `TYPE`s .

- All Criterias: `SELECT distinct(CRITERIA_ID) FROM stackoverflow.Results;`
- All Types `SELECT distinct(TYPE) FROM stackoverflow.Results;`

But how combine them into a view or smth. like this?

If you like to play with the data. This is a script to generate the table:

```
CREATE SCHEMA `stackoverflow`;
CREATE TABLE `stackoverflow`.`Results` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TYPE` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CRITERIA_ID` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `RESULT` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `stackoverflow`.`Results`
(
 `ID`,
 `TYPE`,
 `CRITERIA_ID`,
 `RESULT`
)
VALUES
( 1, "car", env, true ),
( 2, "car", gas, false ),
( 3, "car", age, false ),
( 4, "bike", env, true ),
( 5, "bike", gas, false ),
( 6, "bike", age, true ),
( 7, "bus", env, true ),
( 8, "bus", gas, true ),
( 9, "bus", age, true );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function which is basically what you are trying to do.  So you will need to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT type,
  sum(case when criteria_id = 'env' then result end) env,
  sum(case when criteria_id = 'gas' then result end) gas,
  sum(case when criteria_id = 'age' then result end) age
FROM results
group by type
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9622c/2)

Now if you want to perform this dynamically, meaning you do not know ahead of time the columns to transpose, then you should review the following article:

[Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

Your code would look like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(IF(CRITERIA_ID = ''',
      CRITERIA_ID,
      ''', RESULT, NULL)) AS ',
      CRITERIA_ID
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  Results;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT type, ', @sql, ' FROM Results GROUP BY type');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9622c/4)

Comment: +1 for implementing prepared statements. Dynamic SQL is probably underappreciated. The caveat: cannot be used in functions or triggers.