# Show rows data into column format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in mysql data base in following format-

```
itemName      Date      isAvailable
abc        1/12/2012    yes
xyz        1/12/2012    No
aaa        1/12/2012    yes

abc        2/12/2012    no
xyz        2/12/2012    no
aaa        2/12/2012    yes

abc        3/12/2012    no
xyz        3/12/2012    yes
aaa        3/12/2012    yes
new        3/12/2012    yes
```

I want to collect data into following format-

```
itemName   1/12/2012    2/12/2012   3/12/2012
abc       yes             no        no
xyz       no              no        yes
aaa       yes             yes       yes
new        -              -         yes
```

Any help?

Comment: Hi Indra, welcom to SO. Can you show us some code that demonstrates the way you arrive at this format?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899647/select-dynamic-columns-in-mysql

Comment: You need a query that outputs that data in the format you need and then you need to execute that query into result set and then loop over your result set

Comment: @Steve yes i only fire select query on my table

Comment: @Steve i m looking for query which will give me that format afte

Comment: Can you upload your own code?

Comment: Your output table contains only four columns or it changes dynamically

Comment: Please see Oracle SQL example here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065815/get-the-database-table-values-in-matrix-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT itemName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE Date_format(`Date`,'%Y-%d-%m') WHEN '2012-01-12' THEN `isAvailable` ELSE NULL END) AS `2012-01-12`
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE Date_format(`Date`,'%Y-%d-%m') WHEN '2012-02-12' THEN `isAvailable` ELSE NULL END) AS `2012-02-12`
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE Date_format(`Date`,'%Y-%d-%m') WHEN '2012-03-12' THEN `isAvailable` ELSE NULL END) AS `2012-03-12`
FROM Table1
GROUP BY `itemName`;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20e4c/12)

Comment: thanks... your code is working but there is little bit change in my data i have N/A value and  it is showing as  0

Comment: @IndraYadav - N/A value in which column? Show your exact data (few) in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20e4c/12)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a PIVOT operation when you transform rows into columns. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830960/how-to-pivot-table-with-t-sql) is an example on SO.

Some DBMS will have special commands to deal with that (Like SQl Server that has PIVOT and UNPIVOT). I dont know if mysql has anything.

If you google "T-SQL PIVOT" you will find several examples on how to do it using just T_SQL